# NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription purpose issue

Tags: ios, swift

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "my application name" **Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:**

ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

I got this message from App Store Team. It says that your delivery was successful but I forget to add purpose for the  NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription for location purpose.

if now I submit the application for review.Is there a chance that the application is rejected or it will submit successfully.

is it okay to update this change in next delivary

Comment: This is not really a relevant question for stackoverflow. Ask this question to Apple staff, we have no idea what they think about these kinds of things.

Comment: This time apple will not reject your app but next time make sure to add Description for your NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key, if you will not use Location then remove this key from info.plist file